# How to make a variable final and assign it a value inside initState()

Tags: flutter, dart

What's the best way to make the `AnimationController` `final` in a `StatefulWidget`, the below codes give error.

```
final AnimationController _controller; // I want to keep it final

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this); // error
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [explained by Rémi Rousselet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56707353/179715), you can't.

If you *absolutely* need `_controller` to be `final` (why?), then you could work around it by wrapping it in another object (e.g. a custom class, a `List`, ...) and mutating that.  For example:

```dart
class Boxed<T> {
  T value;
}

final _controller = Boxed<AnimationController>();

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller.value = AnimationController(vsync: this);
}
```

Comment: That kind of defeat the purpose of the final though. Since its `Boxed.value` is not final.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Right, the point is to defeat the purpose of `final` if you're forced to use it (e.g. in an `@immutable` class).  It's not really any different form a `final List<E>`.  Omitting `final` in the first place would be better and clearer, but it's not really clear why the OP wants it.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. `initState` cannot be used to initialize `final` variables.

Even then, there is no way to assign an `AnimationController` to a final property as it depends on `this`.

Comment: Thanks Remi, for simplicity, I used `AnimationController` example.

Answer (score 1):

You can now do that with `late` keyword.

```dart
late final AnimationController _controller;
  
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);
}
```

Comment: is there any difference of using `late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this)` inside the state class and skip `initState`, instead of declaring the late final variable and initializing inside `initState` ?

Comment: @swedishcheef No, there's no difference, you can definitely do that, but the OP was asking for initializing the variable in `initState` method.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks for your reply. I was just asking for my own sake :)